# overlay covering whole page

Tags: html, css

I want to create an overlay that I will use behind a popup. But when the page is scrolled down the overlay is no more there? I can use javascript to get the height of page's content and then can apply same height to overlay but is there any css based solution?

```
#overlay{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   background-color:#000;
   opacity: .75
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable whole page with an overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945268/disable-whole-page-with-an-overlay)

Answer (score 4):

just change the `position` attribute to `fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
```

Try that, i'm not sure if it works on anything but backgrounds but its worth a shot!