# Disable whole page with an overlay

Tags: html, css

I want to create an overlay that I will use behind a popup. But when the page is scrolled down the overlay is no more there? I can use javascript to get the height of page's content and then can apply same height to overlay but is there any css based solution?

```
#overlay{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   background-color:#000;
   opacity: .75
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [overlay covering whole page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937100/overlay-covering-whole-page)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just change the `position` attribute to `fixed`.

Comment: Damn IE6. It seems to be the best solution. Thank you @Tooraj.

Comment: @user1444021 do not forget about `z-index`

Answer (score 8):

`position` must be `fixed` and also to prevent stacking problems add `z-index: 9999999;`
**[demo on dabblet.com](http://dabblet.com/gist/2894437)**

```
#overlay{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity: .75;
    z-index: 9999999;
}
```